# geom_path error while using ggplot to make a line chart with two lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a dataframe by selecting columns from another dataframe, performed a few functions to get in the format I wanted then tried to use it to create a line plot with two lines (one for 2006, one for 2020). When I did, I got this error twice:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
> adjust the group aesthetic?

I have tried:

-ungrouping

-adding "group = YEAR" or "group = 1" to aes()

-switching the x-axis to a column with a numeric value

Nothing worked.

Results of dput(deaths_total):

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L
), month_num2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), monthly_deaths = c(10L, 5L, 
35L, 36L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 12L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 25L, 
9L, 15L, 34L, 4L, 3L, 13L, 14L, 9L), month_name = c("January", 
"February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February", 
"March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), groups = 
structure(list(
YEAR = c(2006L, 2020L), .rows = structure(list(13:24, 1:12), ptype = 
integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Current Code:

```
deaths_graph2 <- ggplot(deaths_total, aes(x = month_name, y = monthly_deaths, colour = YEAR)) 
+
geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide us some data to work with? Maybe try to post the output of `dput()` applied to a meaningful subset of your data.

Comment: @PlasticMan Just did.

Comment: Remove the line break at the end of the ggplot line, the + plus sign should not be on a separate line.  Also, you will want to add "group=YEAR" to the aes definition.

Comment: @Dave2e that worked, but now instead of having one line for "2006" and one for "2020" it filled in the in-between for the legend.

Comment: @Leah I do not have `StormEvents_details.ftp_v1.0_d2020_c20220217_Filtered`.

Comment: Yes, because Year is a continuous variable.  Change it to a factor and then that should work. `color=factor(YEAR)`

Answer (score 0):

The below code fixed the problem

```
deaths_graph2 <- ggplot(deaths_total, aes(x = month_name, y=monthly_deaths, 
group=YEAR, color=factor(YEAR))) + geom_line()
```

It looks like there may have also been a bit of leftover code from a previous attempt that caused the "group =" fix not to work the first time. "color=factor(YEAR)" also solved an issue I was having with the legend.